# Visual studio code doesn't show latest version of npm packages on hover

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code

In package.json I used to check latest versions of packages as a "tooltip" with just pass the mouse on each package version, but it doesn't show anymore.
My VSC version is 1.19.2.
I navigate through a proxy.
I've checked that my workspace settings is empty, and my user settings has this:

```
{
    "vsicons.projectDetection.autoReload": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,

    "http.proxy": "____myproxyIP____",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 11):

Please check, if you have the correct language mode `JSON` and not `JSONc` (JSON with Comments).

Take a look at the bottom right corner.

Correct:

[image]

Incorrect:
[image]